# How to @mention persons and organizations in LinkedIn posts using the API?

Tags: linkedin-api, mention

I'm trying to publish posts on LinkedIn using their API.
Based on their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2024-01&tabs=http#mentions-and-hashtags-using-posts-commentary) (section: Mentions and Hashtags using Posts commentary) I need to use the person's (or organization's) URN and set in the commentary field:

```json
{
  "author": "urn:li:organization:123456789",
  "commentary": "Hello @[Devtestco](urn:li:organization:2414183)",
  "visibility": "PUBLIC",
  "distribution": {
      "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
      "targetEntities": [],
      "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
  },
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false
}
```

**My question is: How/where do I get a person's URN?**
Do they have an API I can call and simply copy/paste a person's LinkedIn profile URL to then get their URN to mention them in the post?

So far I can't find in their documentation how to get a person's `urn:li:person`.
Only found how and where to use it, but not how to actually get it.

Comment: Also struggling with finding the URN value, I asked linkedin support and they have just pointed me to Stackoverflow.... I think if you haven't tidied your linkedin profile url then it maybe the number within that link, but I tidied mine up years ago and cannot find it anywhere in my profile now.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need access to the Community Management API. Once you have that you can use the People typeahead to search within your own connections (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/posts-atmention-search-api?view=li-lms-2024-02&tabs=http)

e.g

https://api.linkedin.com/rest/peopleTypeahead?q=memberConnections&keywords=foo

or alternatively the vanityName lookup which requires the full linkedin url of the profile you want

[https://api.linkedin.com/rest/vanityUrl?q=vanityUrlAsOrganization&vanityUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fhello-world%2F&organization={organizationUrn}](https://api.linkedin.com/rest/vanityUrl?q=vanityUrlAsOrganization&vanityUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fhello-world%2F&organization=%7BorganizationUrn%7D)

Both of these will return the person ID for your app. Unfortunately getting approval isn't such a walk in the park.